# Why does Scala type inferencing fail here

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming, type-inference

Why do right-associative operators have issues with generic-typed functions, even though equivalent left-associative operators work just fine.

```
implicit class FunctionWrapper[T1, T2](func: T1 => T2) {
  def >>>[T3](funcAfter: T2 => T3): T1 => T3 = {
    func andThen funcAfter
  }

  def >>:[T0](funcBefore: T0 => T1): T0 => T2 = {
    funcBefore andThen func
  }
}
```

Following are the functions to be chained:

```
def intToFloat = Int.int2float _
def floatToString = (_: Float).toString
def identityF[T] = identity(_: T)
```

As expected, both operators work well with concrete-typed functions:

```
scala> (intToFloat >>> floatToString)(11)
res5: String = 11.0

scala> (intToFloat >>: floatToString)(11)
res6: String = 11.0
```

However, the >>: fails with generic-typed functions for some reason:

```
scala> (intToFloat >>> identityF >>> floatToString)(11)
res7: String = 11.0

scala> (intToFloat >>: identityF >>: floatToString)(11)
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Nothing => Nothing
 required: T0 => Float
       (intToFloat >>: identityF >>: floatToString)(11)
                                 ^
```

There are workarounds for this, one being

```
(intToFloat >>: (identityF (_: Float)) >>: floatToString)(11)
```

but it seems easy to infer the type of identityF in the given context, why does it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a right-associative operator, remember it's really

```
floatToString.>>:(identityF).>>:(intToFloat)
```

Since there is no type parameter given for `identityF`, it's governed by [local type inference](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#local-type-inference) rules. In this case it tries to find `identityF`'s type parameter first (I think, but the other way around runs into trouble as well); because `>>:`'s type parameter is still unknown, it doesn't know the argument type of the function. It gives up by inferring `Nothing` and then fails to find a suitable type parameter for `>>:`.

With `andThen` or `>>>`, Scala knows expected argument type for `identityF` already and so can infer the correct type parameter.

That is, the problem isn't that `>>:` is right-associative, it's the asymmetry between argument and return types. If you define `>>:[T0](f: T1 => T0)` it'll work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It seems from this and related questions that Scala's type inferencing mechanism is just not powerful enough for the time-being. Over here it seems to be following a "greedy" approach and giving up too soon, because clearly it is possible to infer the type of identityF from intToFloat's and floatToString's types.

Comment: Yes, it never even gets to considering `intToFloat`. On the other hand, subtyping complicates type inference a lot. Making it more powerful could make it even less predictable and hard to specify.